# Genetic distance over spatial scales

Tags: r, variance, spatial, distance

I have matrices of genetic distances for x number of individuals within a population and their corresponding point coordinates -one genetic distance matrix per point coordinates.

I was imagining using the **Mantel test**, i.e. evaluate the significance of correlations between genetic and geographic distances. However, what I did not think of was that these two types of matrices will have different dimensions (e.g. a genetic matrix of 15 ind = 15x15, sampled at three locations = 3x3), hence the **Mantel test** will not work. I am now looking into **Moran's I**, testing for spatial autocorrelation, but it will not work with my data as it currently is. I would need one measure of variation per point coordinates. Would it be legit (never seen anyone do this) to derive a measure of variation (e.g. **var**, **sd**, **cv**) from a single distance matrix? Since the matrix is normalized, ranging from 0-1, maybe **var** or **sd** would work?

I am kinda new to analyzing spatial data, so I would appreciate any pointers or alternative tests I might be able to do.

Thanks,

Comment: I am sure that you find useful information in this question (it also contain links to useful articles) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72685/why-is-mantels-test-preferred-over-morans-i

Comment: @LadislavNado Cheers for commenting. Yeah, I have read through this already. It's a good one.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry but with just 3 locations you can forget about spatial statistics - you won't be able to calculate Moran's I or Mantel properly (believe me such approach will be hard to defend in peer-review), and i think you should do some simple "ANOVA-like" analysis instead (try to explain variability within and between groups).

Comment: @LadislavNado Ah, yeah you're probably right. Cheers

Comment: ...Im thinking of **adonis** {vegan} analysis which is a non-parametric version of **MANOVA**

Comment: I will look on it {adonis} - (may be it will solve not only your problem be my problem also). Thanks you for it! I contact you later.

Comment: Now, after reading and trying to understand various tests, I think **Betadisper** {vegan} would work for me. It tests if groups differ in their variance compared to **adonis** which tests the difference in centroid position. It is basically **Levene's test for homogeneity of variances/homoscedasticity** which assesses the equality of variances for a variable *(genetic distance)* calculated for two or more groups *(locations)*.